# Extract expressions with square brackets

Tags: r, stringr

The example I have is as follow:

```
toMatch <- c("[1]", "[2]", "[3]")

names <- c("apple[1]", "apple", "apple[3]")
```

I want extract the terms in `names` which contains one of the patterns in `toMatch`.

This is what I tried

```
grep(toMatch, names, value=T)
```

But, it didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you rewrite `toMatch`? Since `[1]` has special meaning in matching, rather than inserting a bunch of escapes, you could do something like `Vectorize(grep, 'pattern')(toMatch, names, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: could you do `sapply(toMatch, grep, names, value=TRUE)`

Comment: @user20650 that makes more sense than mine, but op wants fixed=TRUE methinks, even tho you are getting the right answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `[` character used in `toMatch` is an reserved character with special meaning in `regex/pattern`. Hence, we need to first replace `[` character with `\\[`.

Now, collapse `toMatch` with `|` and then use it as `pattern` in `grepl` function to search matching character in `names`.

The solution results are:

```
#Just for indexes
grepl(paste0(gsub("(\\[)","\\\\[",toMatch), collapse = "|"), names)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

#For values
grep(paste0(gsub("(\\[)","\\\\[",toMatch), collapse = "|"), names, value = TRUE)
#[1] "apple[1]" "apple[3]"
```

**Data:**

```
toMatch <- c("[1]", "[2]", "[3]")

names <- c("apple[1]", "apple", "apple[3]")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @user9382972 Happy it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

We could also remove the letter part and create a logical vector with `%in%`

```
names[sub("^[^[]*", "", names) %in% toMatch]
#[1] "apple[1]" "apple[3]"
```